# Set outline:none for a, :hover and :active but enable browser default for :focus

Tags: css, accessibility

I have button styles that look like this:

```
.submit-button {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    outline: none;
}
```

Can I add a `:focus` state, and then set the outline to whatever the browser default outline is?

```
.submit-button:focus {
     outline: browser-default;
}
```

I tried `outline: inherit;` but this had no effect on the page.

Comment: you might want to take a look at a few css reset stylesheets, and pick out the few lines of code that would reset your button.

Comment: I'm not sure that would help.. I want to override the browser default focus in the input default state, and then set it again in a pseudo-selector.

Comment: Can you just remove the `outline:none;` from the stylesheet in the first place? Or is there a specific reason why you want to remove it, and then put it back, rather than just not using the `outline: none;` at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:not()` pseudo-class, like this:

```
.submit-button:not(:focus) {
    outline: none;
}
```

Doing so would prevent the selector to override the defaults on `:focus`.

The best part, is that the `:not()` pseudo-class is understandable by all browsers who understand the `:focus` as well.